# Calling a class from another program which they are in different locations

Tags: java, call

I have two programs and I have to call a program which is in different location i.e., say calling program is in d://start and called program is in f://call. How to do it in java?

Can I use this method to be implemented in calling program?

```
try
{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
       new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "F:/call.java"});

    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = p.outputStream();
}

catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @NandkumarTekale I have two programs. one is GUI and another one application to rip words in java. I have to call the class which contains the main method when I click the button from the GUI program. Well in your way call the main method from another class in another location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run another Java program by `exec` a command like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java /directory/com/Main.java")
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp /directory/package.jar com.Main")
```

If you need to call methods on that class within the same JVM you can try to [load the jar at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime) and then call the classes reflectively.